# Problema en login, si los datos son invalidos no muestra la alerta de error de usuario

Tags: php, ajax

Saludos, de nuevo por aquí. Tengo un login que valida por tipos de usuario mediante AJAX la cual hace la petición a PHP, al momento de introducir tanto username como password que existan en la tabla usuarios, no hay problema, se loguea bien.

El problema surge cuando alguno de los dos datos es invalido, osea que el usuario no existe con alguno de los dos datos, el login esta hecho de manera que cuando eso pase me muestre un div con una alerta de que los datos son inválidos.

Pero resulta que eso no pasa, cuando hay algún dato invalido el login se queda "Validando" y no hace nada, no muestra la alerta. Se queda pegado validando y no me hace nada. No consigo el error por ningún lado, esta es la petición con AJAX:

```
  jQuery(document).on('submit','#login', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  jQuery.ajax({
  url:'login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#boton').val('Validando...');
  }
 })
 .done(function(respuesta){
  console.log(respuesta);
  if(!respuesta.error){
    if(respuesta.tipo == 'Admin'){
      location.href = 'admin/admin.php';
    }else if(respuesta.tipo == 'Limitado'){
      location.href = 'limitado/limitado.php';
  }else{
    $('#alerta').slideDown('slow');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#alerta').slideUp('slow');
    },3000);
    $('#boton').val('Iniciar Sesión');
  }
 }
 })
 .fail(function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
 })
 .always(function(){
  console.log("completo");
 });
 });
```

Y este es el PHP:

```
 <?php

 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
 strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
 require('lib/conexion.php');
 sleep(1);
  session_start();

  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

  $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nick']);
  $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

  if($new_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nick,tipo_usuario FROM usuarios
  WHERE nick = ? AND password = ?")){
  $new_consulta->bind_param('ss',$usuario,$pass);

  $new_consulta->execute();

  $result = $new_consulta->get_result();

  if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $datos = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos;
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>false,'tipo'=>$datos['tipo_usuario']));
  }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>true));
  }
  $new_consulta->close();
}
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Tengo rato buscando el error, pero no consigo cual sea el problema. Gracias de antemano quien me ayude.!

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si tus condiciones las cambias de la siguiente forma `if (respuesta.error === true){} else if (respuesta.error === false){}`?

Comment: Vamooos. Eso era. Como no me he dado cuenta! Muchas gracias Lixus.! Manito arriba para ti.!

Comment: Luxis pero ahora no me loguea cuando los datos son correcto!

Comment: Entonces tu PHP no está haciendo el logueo o validando que se logueo correctamente, intenta debuguear el `if / else` para validar que esté entrando en ambas condiciones según se cumplan

Comment: Que me queres decir con debuguear? disculpa

Comment: ¿Qué imprime `console.log(respuesta);`?

Comment: cuando no se loguea, imprime completo! esta respondiendo bien.! y cuando he cambiado lo que me dijo lixus las condiciones de true y false, cuando los datos son correctos no se loguea y el console.log dice completo igual y presiono F5 y si entra al usuario. es extraño